# Interface Builder is unable to open documents of type CocoaTouch XIB

Tags: interface-builder, ios4

I just installed the laster XCode and iOS SDK and I keep getting the following error when I open a XIB file.

"Interface Builder is unable to open documents of type CocoaTouch XIB."

Comment: I have just found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9943919/246119

Answer (score 0):

if you are using xcode 4.2.3 or newer version of then you have to no need to set HEADER SEARCH PATH. if you had added these two lines then remove it.

"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../three20"

"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../three20"