# Interface builder is unable to open documents of type iPad XIB

Tags: objective-c

I got a application from my teammate, and it is for both iphone and ipad devices (which it is developed under iPhone SDK 3.2).

I have iPhone SDK 3.1.3 installed in my mac book. When i tried to compile the application for iphone simulator i got the following error.

Interface builder is unable to open documents of type iPad XIB.

The above error is for interface builder created for ipad.

My Question is we can't compile the application on iPhone SDK 3.1.3 which the application developed under iPhone SDK 3.2?

Please shed some light of this?

thanks
mindus

Answer (score 6):

Go to your project settings, and delete the line that says Interface Builder Plugin search path or something similar.

the exact line in project.pbxproj is: IBC_PLUGIN_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PROJECT_DIR}/**";

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

Temporarily remove the iPad xib when working with the 3.1.3 SDK. Put them back when you go back to 3.2 and above.

**Longer answer**

This cropped up for me when compiling against 3.1.3. You can use conditional compiling to get code user newer features to build successfully (see [Matt Gallagher's helpful post on conditional compiling](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html)).

There may be a smarter way to tell the compiler not to look at the iPad xibs. For testing on the 3.1.3 simulator I simply made a copy all my iPad xibs and then removed them from the xcode project. When going back to my current development set up, you have to put them back. It's a bit of pain, but not that fiddly.

Answer (score 0):

**To fix this:**

1. Press Command-1 to go to the project tree
2. Select your project
3. The in the right panel select your project, and then click on "Build Settings"
4. In search field just below the "Build Settings" enter: "Overriding Plug-In"
5. Now, the only visible setting left should say "Overriding Plug-In and Framework Directory"
6. Double-click the value and remove all entries using "-" button
7. Click somewhere else so settings are saved

That should fix it