# Creating Coverflow of menus using Tabku library but cant include header file

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, xcode4.3

I have created app for cover flow of menus.i have followed a tutorial including tabku library in my project.I've done all the steps which is in following link

http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=657

But it throws error as ' file not found'.Here is my code below.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <TabkuLibrary/TabkuLibrary.h>


@interface ViewController :UIViewController<TKCoverflowViewDelegate,TKCoverflowViewDataSource>{
TKCoverFlowView * Coverflow;
NSMutableArray *arr;
}

@end
```

I've followed so many tutorials and ended up in the above link...Can anyone help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is actually called Tapku and I ran into the same problem. I ended up adding $(SRCROOT)/tapkulibrary/src to my search header path, and then got a different error: "Interface Builder is unable to open documents of type CocoaTouch XIB." Fortunately the above error was fixed thanks to another SO thread: [Interface builder is unable to open documents of type iPad XIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499751/interface-builder-is-unable-to-open-documents-of-type-ipad-xib)