# Error determining type of data

Tags: ios, xcode4.3

when I tried to add new XIB file, and then open the main storyboard in interface builder, an error returned that interface builder cannot determine the type of data!

I do not know why?

can anyone help please

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project settings, and delete the line that says Interface Builder Plugin search path or something similar.

the exact line in project.pbxproj is: IBC_PLUGIN_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PROJECT_DIR}/**";

Source: [Interface builder is unable to open documents of type iPad XIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499751/interface-builder-is-unable-to-open-documents-of-type-ipad-xib)

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm using xcode 4.6 now I cannot find the key mentioned it is empty

Comment: I've located the line but also removing it does not solve the issue